# Order by condition with string conversion in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I tried to get amount and date values from a SQL Server database using the query

```
select Amount, RunDate
  from zComm
 WHERE ID = '1339812'
```

It is not returning any data. But when I convert date to string it is working query is

```
select Amount, convert(varchar, RunDate) as RunDate
  from zComm
 WHERE ID = '1339812'
```

Now I want to show the `Amount` in the descending order of `RunDate` and I used the query

```
select Amount, convert(varchar, RunDate) as RunDate 
  from zComm 
 WHERE ID = '1339812'
 order by RunDate;
```

But the result I got is not in descending order. I have attached the screenshot of the result query.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `DESC` keyword. So your query would become

```
SELECT Amount, convert(varchar, RunDate) as RunDateChar  
FROM zComm  
WHERE ID = N'1339812'
ORDER BY RunDate DESC;
```

It is likely it is ordering by the `CHAR` representation and not the date.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The sorting is being done on the string representation of the date, try this.

```
select Amount, convert(varchar, RunDate) as RunDateVarchar
  from zComm 
 WHERE ID='1339812'
 order by RunDate;
```

Comment: The idea that it's ordering by a string doesn't match with the last three records (`'Nov 12'`, `'Nov 3 '`, `'Nov 1 `'). If ordered by a string, the two `'Nov 1'` records should be next to each other.  Also, it looks like the OP's exampel query is missing a `DESC`.  In short, I'm not convinced that the OP has given us the full and correct information.